# How express `others` in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an SQL query where the condition goes as following:

```
select ......
FROM TABLE1, TABLE2
where ....... 
AND TABLE1.TYPE = CASE WHEN TABLE2.TYPE = 2 THEN 'S' ELSE (NOT S)
```

How can I express this `NOT S`? i.e. I want the query to result in rows where `TABLE1.TYPE` = `S` WHEN `TABLE2.TYPE` is `2`, or when `TABLE1.TYPE` is anything but `S` when `TABLE2.TYPE` is anything but `2`.

I am running this query on Oracle 11S2.

Comment: Please read and understand Gordon's answer, which is the right way to express what you needed. Then you may spend a few minutes reading this:  http://xyproblem.info/  -  to understand what's wrong with the way you asked the question. You asked how to do something YOUR way (which was already going in the wrong direction), instead of asking about the "original" thing you needed to solve for.

Comment: @mathguy that's not the case. I did state the original problem, only I mentioned what I tried to solve it, which is the right approach when asking questions on SO. I did the `Always include information about a broader picture along with any attempted solution.` part...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use simple logic, not a `case`:

```
where . . . and
      (table2.type = 2 and table1.type = 'S' or
       table2.type <> 2 and table2.type <> 'S'
      )
```

This assumes that that columns do not take on `NULL` values.  This can easily be handled but somewhat complicates the expressions.